# Android ExifInterface get photo date return null in HTC sensation

Tags: android, date

I try to get the photo date from HTC Sensation 4.0.3 O.S version.

I use the ExifInterface to  get the photo metadata.

```
 public static String getPhotoDate(String path)
{
    ExifInterface intf = null;
    try
    {
        intf = new ExifInterface(path);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(intf != null)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,":intf:"+intf);

        String TAG_FLASH = intf.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH);
        String dateString = intf.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
        return dateString;
    }
    return "";
}
```

But the code in Sony Xperia is correct, that can get the photo date.

In the HTC sensation get photo is null.

But I can see the photo date in the photo detail info.

[image]

Have anyone know how to get the photo date in HTC cellphone?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
if(file.exists())
{
Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());    
Log.i("Dated : "+ lastModDate.toString());
}
```